# Android moving time back break the activity lifecycle

Tags: android

I notice some bug in my app and try to test it on blank project.
I create 2 activities FirstActivity and SecondActivity.
FirstActivity have a button "Go to SecondActivity"
I start the app, press the button after I go to the phone settings and change system time to one hour ago and restore app.
After this manipulation all the lifecycle methods does not log events. onStart, onResume even onBackPressed does not logged (but actually working). This is happen in SecondActivity and in FirstActivity too. This is happen also even if I does not open SecondActivity and stay in First one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find I logs in terminal logcat.
Or if I move time only for 5 min back and wait for it - logs appears in android studio as well.